# Visual Studio : Search Uncommented Code only

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to restrict the Find/Search to uncommented lines only ? 
(Maybe using regex would be a good lead)

Comment: You can always collapse the commented code and uncheck "search hidden text".

Comment: Not a direct duplicate, but I asked a related question a while ago and got some helpful suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872946/are-there-any-context-sensitive-code-search-tools

Comment: @bzlm: Dude, I am searching the entire solution :-)

Comment: regex will definitely work for lines starting with // but it's going to be some crazy regex to skip those contained in /**/

Comment: Is there a solution for VS 2015? I tried the only given answer but it didn't seem to work and instead would never find anything..

Answer (score 5):

Lets say, if you need to search all occurrences of an uncommented text "VPEntity" then try using the following regular expression in Find in files after selecting the Use RegEx option

```
^((?!//|/\*).)*VPEntity
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: or use this ^((?!//|/\*).)*VPEntity*$ or you can tweak it as per your need using any RegEx Builder tool

Comment: and for VB.Net code it is `^((?!').)*VPEntity.*$` The .+ at the end is important, otherwise it won't match unless VPEntity is at the end of the line. This could be more robust I'm sure since a ' anywhere before the term in the line will prevent a match, not just the beginning.